# Robust regression in R using lmrob from robustbase

Tags: r, regression, robust

I am currently working on data that requires usage of robust regression.
Since I am new to this topic of robust regression I am not sure how to best calculate the F-stat for my regression model as `summary(lmrob)` normally does not return an F-statistic.
Here are my questions:

Is the concept of F-stats even applicable to robust regression?
If not, which other tests can I use and how do I perform them in terms of coding?
If yes, how can I code the F-test for `lmrob` objects?

Comment: You say you use robust regression, but it's not clear which package `lmrob` comes from: there's `robust`, `robustBase`. Robust regression is not a method, rather it is a consequence of a particular method (whether trimming outliers, rank transforming, or perhaps using the "MM-like" method) and it pertains to a particular type of assumption violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The robustbase package has an anova.lmrob function for performing a robust analysis of deviance for two competing, nested linear regression models m1 and m2 fitted by lmrob - for example, m1 includes only an intercept and m2 which includes the intercept plus all the predictors you are interested in say, X1 and X2):

```
m1 <- lmrob(Y ~ 1, data = yourdata)

m2 <- lmrob(Y ~ 1 + X1 + X2, data = yourdata)

anova(m2, m1, test = "Deviance")
```

In the anova command, the models are forced to be listed from largest (m2) to smallest (m1) due to computational reasons.

The anova output will return a P-value comparing the reduction in robust deviance achieved by including the predictors in the intercept-only model. If this reduction is significant, then the inclusion of the predictors is warranted.

Comment: But it probably won't use a (finite sample) F-test. Robust regression doesn't mean anything specific. At the very least, we desire robustness to an assumption of normality of residuals. In that case, using the asymptotic chi-square test stat is, in a sense, robust.

Comment: @AdamO: lmrob specifically attempts to provide robustness to outliers, so I am not sure I understand your robustness to the assumption of normality comment.

Comment: The F-test statistic is proportional to the ratio of variances under the full and reduced models. It only actually takes an F-distribution under the null if the residuals are in fact normal. There's an interesting debacle of probability vs. statistics: will normally distributed residuals yield outliers? If you delete them, the distribution is no longer normal and the F-test is invalid.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! I think I will go with AdamO's first suggestion, I really like the idea of comparing the robust regression model with a model with only an intercept. Besides, I am using Tukeys bisquare estimator, do you think that in this case anything about testing changes?